# Genexus grid prompt turns disabled after first selection

Tags: javascript, java, genexus

I am working in a multiple level transaction in genexus X Ev2, and I have some problems with a level 1 grid with prompts for each line of the grid.

The level 1 Grid gets the information from another transaction in the form of a prompt on image click `prompt(hSel,keytransaction, keytransaction2, DEMDETUSOIDL) on &USOSELIMG`. Where `DEMDETUSOIDL` is the key of the table the level is referencing.

It creates a javascript for each line, for example: At the third line of the grid it makes: `javascript:gx.evt.execEvt('EVUSOSELIMG.GXPROMPT.0003',gx.dom.el('DEMDETUSOIDL_0003'),false,true);`

And after I use the prompt and select an item, the prompt gets disabled and makes an "undefined" Javascript: `javascript:gx.evt.execEvt('EVUSOSELIMG.GXPROMPT.undefined',gx.dom.el('DEMDETLIN_undefined'),false,true);`

It also changes the `DEMDETUSOIDL` (the primary key of the item I'm prompting), and it changes to the key of the level (DEMDETLIN). It might be worth noting that DEMDETLIN is serialed:

```
Serial(DEmDetLin, DEmUltLin,1);
NoAccept( DEmDetLin );
```

Is this an known problem? does it have a solution?

Update1: 
I noticed this error happens when the key of a level changes from 0 to the serial value, usually triggered by pressing tab or by a click in other element.
Is there a way to delay the serial?

Update2: it also happens when I change values from a detail line.

Final Update (Solution Found):

It seems Genexus has problems when using prompts with rules "ON &img" in a grid.
If normal prompt rule is used, the problem solves by itself. I was using a prompt with "lots" of aditional information loaded, so I needed to use On Image, after noticing that might be the problem. I just had to use a procedure to load the additional data on After.

Answer (score 0):

There are some documents of GeneXus that refer to similar problems. Depending the issue, the browser / version is also part of the problem (or solution).
[SAC 34403](https://www.genexus.com/developers/websac?en,,,34403)
[SAC 36732](https://www.genexus.com/developers/websac?en,,,36732)
Anyway, some additional comments:

1. having a grid in the first level is not supported in a transaction.
2. Evolution 2 is from 2012, it may be a good option to test this with Evolution 3 or GeneXus 15.
3. Seems that contacting GeneXus support is a good option too. [Link](http://www.genexus.com/issuetracking)